# Embedded Spotify player as in Musixmatch

Tags: javascript, web, iframe, spotify

As you might know, for now, it's impossible to embed a Spotify player through their suggested code.

However, I noticed that Musixmatch solves it by setting their web as a device (premium & auth are needed), but I have no idea how to do it, and I've not found anything about it.

Is anyone here know how to do that or think about another solution for this?

Spotify window while syncing song on Musixmatch

[image: 1]

Musixmatch custom Spotify player

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [Web Playback SDK](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/) you can use, but then you have to make the UI yourself.